# question about union notation

Tags: notation

$\left\{a\right\}\cup\left\{b\right\}\cup\left\{c\right\}$ can be written as $\bigcup\left\{\left\{a\right\},\left\{b\right\},\left\{c\right\}\right\}$ can it not?

Comment: Yes, it can be written that way.

Comment: Indeed. Generally, $\bigcup \mathscr A = \bigcup\limits_{A\in\mathscr A}A$ where $\mathscr A$ is a family of sets.

Comment: it is the other way around :) that is, $\bigcup\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c\}\}$ could be written as $\{a\}\cup\{b\}\cup\{c\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. More generally, for any sets $A,B,C,$
$$
\bigcup\{A,B,C\}=A\cup B\cup C.$$
And of course the same goes for any number of sets.